# how to use SIFT features for bag of words in opencv?

Tags: opencv, sift, multilabel-classification

I have read a lot of articles about implementing bag of words after taking sift features of an image, but I'm still confused what to do next. What do i specifically do?

Thank you so much in advance for the guidance.

This is the code that i have so far.

```
cv::Mat mat_img = cropped.clone();
Mat grayForML;
cvtColor(mat_img, grayForML, CV_BGR2GRAY);
IplImage grayImageForML = grayForML.operator IplImage();


//create another copy of iplGray
IplImage *input = cvCloneImage(&grayImageForML);
Mat matInput = cvarrToMat(input);
//  Mat matInput = copy_gray.clone();
cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPoints;
detector.detect(input, keyPoints);
//add results to image and save.
cv::Mat output;
cv::drawKeypoints(input, keyPoints, output);    //SIFT OUTPUT RESULT


//resize and display
cv::Mat output_reduced;
cv::resize(output, output_reduced, cv::Size2i(output.cols / 2, output.rows / 2));


imshow("SIFT result", output_reduced);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Training a bag of words system goes as follows:

1. Compute the features for each image of the training set
2. Cluster those features
3. Label each cluster with the images that have features in that cluster

At this point the training is done and you can start with the testing as follows:

1. Compute the features of the test image
2. For each feature, find the nearest cluster
3. Add a tick for each training image that belong to this cluster
4. Repeat for all features of the test image
5. The image that has the highest number of ticks is the best match and the image with the second highest number of ticks is the second best match and so on

As you can notice, there is no restriction to using SIFT. You can try different feature extractors and descriptors.

Comment: for step #1, do the SIFT keypoints I was able to get from an image count?

Comment: @lionking yes you can use SIFT .. My advice is that you build the whole pipeline then experiment with different feature extractors

Comment: For #2, you can use algorithms like k-means clustering to form clusters of the training features

Comment: I see. Thank you for your suggestion. I will start experimenting with SIFT. Pardon me for the baby talk, I'm really new to image classification. By #2, I can cluster them features by putting them to separate yml? For xample, banana.xml will contain all features of banana, while rice.xml for all rice features?

Comment: Say you have a training set that contains 100 banana images and 200 rice images, you will compute the features for all the images in the training set. Then apply the kmeans algorithm on those features to cluster them. This in includes the features from all the classes together.

Comment: I would love to believe that I am 60% done. I found this tutorial and it was also really helpful! 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O

I tweaked some parts to fit to my project and I was able to successfully compute descriptor for an image. And according to this tutorial, 
This descriptor can be used to classify the image for several classes. You may use SVM or any other classifier to check the discriminative power and the robustness of this descriptor.

Comment: What kind of clustering are you doing ? Let's say I have 2 classes. 200 descriptors per Image, 5 images of class 1 and 5 images of class 2. Each descriptors is an 128 columns array.
Should I make two list, 1000 descriptors in each and do two clustering model ?
Then I extract the most frequent clusters.
Then to test, I try on first model and see how many descriptors of the test image are in model 1 and model 2 and take the one with the more descriptors ?