# How to use SIFT features/descriptors as input for SVM training?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, sift

I want to classify MRI images of a brain tumor into benign and malignant using C++. I am using SIFT features and the paper I am following clustered them using kmeans before training the SVM classifier. What I don't understand is why is there a need to do that? From what I know, kmeans only clusters the features; it doesn't change the size of the input.

I have read that possible ways are BoW and histogram. **In the histogram approach**, It just counts the # of features in each cluster right? I don't think that will provide the information I'll need for classifying benign and malignant tumors because they can be both small and big. **In BoW approach**, I didn't understand this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928135/how-to-use-sift-features-for-bag-of-words-in-opencv).

Basically, I don't know what to do with my SIFT features to use it as input for SVM. Do I really have to create a dictionary of some sort? I'm begging you, please enlighten me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with OpenCV or SIFT features, but this should be general enough to be useful to all programming languages. I will also be describing only the BoW approach below.

Let's assume we had `N` images. For each image `i`, we have `F` number of features, and each feature had `D` dimensions. We can put all the features into an array `feats`, so that it looks like this:

```
[1, 2, ..., D]
[..., ..., ..., D]
[N*F, ..., ..., D]
```

Each row of `feats` is a feature, with `D` dimensions, and we have a total of `N*F` features.

In k-means, we take all these features and group them into `k` clusters. Therefore, every single feature is assigned to a single cluster. Most k-means functions typically return a matrix `C` of size `k x D`, which represents the centroids of the clusters. This matrix `C` is the "codebook" or "dictionary" of the k-means algorithm. Some also return a vector of size `N*F` which shows which cluster each feature is assigned to (in OpenCv, this is represented by the `labels` variable in this link: http://www.developerstation.org/2012/01/kmeans-clustering-in-opencv-with-c.html).

Since we already have the assignments of all the features, each image `i` has `F` features, which can be simply represented by the clusters they belong to. For example, if the original image was represented as

```
[1, 2, ..., D]
[..., ..., ..., D]
[F, ..., ..., D]
```

then the image can also be represented simply as a vector:

```
[1] % Assignment of feature 1
[...]
[F] % Assignment of feature F
```

Therefore, you can take this vector and form a histogram `h` of the clusters that are represented. This histogram is the feature vector for the image, which you can later use in the SVM.

P.S. If you need any further clarification and/or an example, let me know!

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now! I just have a few more questions.
(1) All the vectors that I will cluster will be coming from images from both classes, right?
(2) Also, in the end, the image will be represented by a histogram of what size? Is it k where each element of the vector is the count of features in that image belonging to that cluster? Or is it F where each element of the vector is the integer of the cluster for which that feature is a part of? I think it's k, did I understand it right?
Thank you!

Comment: (1) The vectors/features that you cluster come from both classes. (2) The histogram is of size `k`. The element `i` in the histogram is the number of times that cluster `i` shows up in the image. I'm glad I could help :D

Comment: Alright then. One last question, I'm sorry. I asked my professor if it's alright to use BoW for my case (given that its disadvantage is that it ignores the spatial relationships among the patches)... But he said no. What do you think? Are there other approaches I should use?

Comment: You could try spatial pyramid matching (SPM). It's similar to BoW, and you can read about it here: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Courses/Fall2014/CS9840/Papers/lazebnikcvpr06b.pdf. This version does consider the spatial relationship between patches. Basically, level 0 of the pyramid is a standard BoW. At level 1, the standard BoW is calculated, and then the image is divided into 4 regions. The histograms of each region are calculated and weighted higher. Therefore, you have 5 histograms which better show the relationship between patches. Let me know if you have specific questions about this.

Comment: I saw LIBPMK but it seems hard to implement. This link [link](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-spatial-pyramid-matching) is the closest I got from understanding SPM. But I didn't understand (for #'s 2-3) what a "coordinate histogram" is, and (for #5) how to know the probability of the k-th visual word. Also, what is the use of the kernel values for SVM-RBF? Thank you very much!